# How can I make my python script wait until I tell it it to continue in the terminal?

Tags: python, command-line, terminal

I'm trying to make the the second print statement wait until I press enter in the command line but I keep getting an unexpected EOF error.

```
print "hi"
continu = input("Press Enter to continue!")
print "hi"
```

Here is my traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "save_cookies.py", line 2, in <module>
    continu = input("Press Enter to continue!")
  File "<string>", line 0

    ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

Comment: how are you running your script? I mean as `python save_cookies.py`?

Comment: Which python version are you using? It looks like you are mixing python2 and python3 statements

Comment: @AyushShanker I'm pressing F5 while in geany.

Comment: Yep, Which Python version are you using?

Comment: If you're using Python 2.x, then change `input` to `raw_input`.

Comment: @dhruvSomani Dainele was right I just needed to use raw_input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your are mixing `python2` and `python3` statements.

For `python2` you need to use `raw_input` ([PEP 3111](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3111/)):

```
print "hi"
raw_input("Press Enter to continue!")
print "hi"
```

For `python3` instead, you need to adjust the syntax on the `print` ([PEP 3105](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3105/)):

```
print("hi")
input("Press Enter to continue!")
print("hi")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `raw_input()` instead of `input()`.